# First fragment is visible even after transacting the second fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following fragment will be done when the user clicks the first item in the navigation view

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm          = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Dashboard                              newFragment = (Dashboard) fm.findFragmentByTag("viewAlbum");
                if (newFragment == null) {
                    newFragment = new Dashboard();
                }
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "viewAlbum")
                        .show(newFragment)
                        .commitAllowingStateLoss();
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

The following fragment will be loaded when the user clicks the second item in navigation view.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm          = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AssigneewiseFragment                   newFragment = (AssigneewiseFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("viewSelectedPlaylist");
            if (newFragment == null) {
                newFragment = new AssigneewiseFragment();
            }
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "viewSelectedPlaylist")
                    .show(newFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The issue is that When the user clicks the second item in navigation view, the assigneewise fragment is loaded but still the first fragment is visible below the second fragment. How can I be able to sort this out?

Comment: you are using add() in case of second fragment. Try replace() instead.

Comment: You have both fragments loaded in frame and haven't set any background to assigneewiseFragment.  After setting some background to main layout of  assigneewiseFragment then it will cover first fragment.

Comment: using replace() again causes the views in first fragment to be laggy during second transaction

Comment: I will try adding background

Comment: setting the background colour hides the first fragment. However, If i click from second fragment then the button thats in first fragment  is being clicked. :(

Comment: For that you have to set parent layout clickable = "true" . It will solve your problem. But I suggest to use replace() instead of add(). Because after loading more fragment  outOfMemory or stackoverflow could cause issue.

Comment: Each time if i replace , the second replacement of the first fragment is not successful

Comment: should I set clickable = true in parent layout of first fragment or second fragment

Comment: On every layout which you're gonna add fragment to content_frame.

Comment: Add clickable="true" and focusable="true" in your every fragment layout and your click issue will be solved and also add background color in your every fragment layout so that previous fragment won't be visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think replace() will solve your problem

for that you need to set background color white or anything and you need to use click listener on your main layout.

Comment: setting the background color did not workout. If any elements on the replaced background have Click listener, then even if you are on new the one, you can still click and trigger them

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` instead of `add`

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm          = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AssigneewiseFragment                   newFragment = (AssigneewiseFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("viewSelectedPlaylist");
            if (newFragment == null) {
                newFragment = new AssigneewiseFragment();
            }
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, "viewSelectedPlaylist")
                    .show(newFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: using replace() again causes the views in first fragment to be laggy during second transaction

Comment: paste the container's xml. Are you using framelayout as container?

Comment: Container is RelativeLayout

Comment: You should use ```Framelayout```